# What are the drawbacks of using autospec in python unittest module

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I don't see any major drawbacks for not using autospecs.

I have gone through the documentation, but I am still not clear: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#auto-speccing

Can someone please explain what this line means with an example.

`If any of your specced objects have properties or descriptors that can trigger code execution then you may not be able to use autospec.`

Comment: I've been using autospec for about a year now and don't see any drawbacks. There are some caveats such as setting side_effects but no draw backs. That line you posted is going to be hard to test with or without autospec.